# Saving Tensorflow model into safetensors format - facing 'list' or 'Sequential' object 'AttributeError' - what's wrong?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem when saving model in Tensorflow into a safetensors format.
After I load my model using `tf.keras.saving.load_model('model')`, and try to save into safetensors. But after I save, I got the error like below

```
>>> save_file(model,'models.safetensors')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rene/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safetensors/tensorflow.py", line 70, in save_file
    np_tensors = _tf2np(tensors)
  File "/home/rene/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safetensors/tensorflow.py", line 135, in _tf2np
    for k, v in tf_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Even I tried to save using model.weights, I also got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rene/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safetensors/tensorflow.py", line 70, in save_file
    np_tensors = _tf2np(tensors)
  File "/home/rene/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safetensors/tensorflow.py", line 135, in _tf2np
    for k, v in tf_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What I expect is the , I can safe the model into safetensors format

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error and fix the issue.